# Power BI - Generating an embed token for multiple tiles/reports

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi

I am trying to display a few tiles/reports on my custom page, and a part of that task involves me generating an embed token for the frontend JS to consume.

Backend is an ASP.NET web application, and I am using the Microsoft.PowerBi.Api V3.11.1 SDK to accomplish this.

I can generate a token for a report/tile by calling `client.Tiles/Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync`, however I am struggling to find a way to generate a token for ***multiple*** tiles/reports. Has anyone come across this?